# How do molecules with opposite rotational photoisomerization bonds behave?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers, photochemistry

If a molecules bond change upon isomerization with the respective bonds straining the molecules as they orient themselves opposite from each other, would the molecule undergo some kind of decomposition?
To expand, and make an example. If there are two bonds in a molecule that undergo photoisomerization that twist the molecule is opposite directions, effectively straining the molecule.

Edit: I am having a lot of hard time explaining this verbally, so I appreciate your patience and time.

Comment: Shouldn't be more logical to think that there is not such a molecule, or better, nothing happens? At least not with the photon you have in mind.

Comment: What do you mean by 'opposite rotational photoisomerisation' ?